# How to solve Type error: is not a valid Page expor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-server-components

am trying to deploy to vercel my next js app but it keeps giving me Type error: Page "app/(adminPanel)/admin/about/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
"AdminAbout" is not a valid Page export field.It works on my local machine on local host but when i try to deploy it not working.

this is the page export default where the error occurs:

```
interface FormProps {
  info: Info;
  exp: Experience;
}

const AdminAbout = async ({ info, exp }: FormProps) => {
  const infos = await prisma.info.findMany();
  const experiences = await prisma.experience.findMany();


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="max-w-7xl px-10 mx-auto space-y-5 md:ml-[17rem] pt-20 min-h-screen">
        <div className=" flex items-center space-x-2 mb-2 shadow-md rounded-lg bg-primary p-4">
          <h1 className="font-bold pl-5 text-primary-foreground">
            Description Form
          </h1>
        </div>
        <InfoForm info={info} />
        <Table>
          <TableCaption>Description Form</TableCaption>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHead className="w-[100px]">Resume</TableHead>
              <TableHead>Description</TableHead>
              <TableHead className="text-right">Action</TableHead>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {infos.map((info) => (
              <TableRow key={info.id}>
                {info.public_id && (
                  <TableCell className="font-medium">
                    <CldImage
                      className="aspect-video"
                      width={100}
                      height={100}
                      src={info.public_id}
                      alt={"pdf"}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                )}
                {/* <TableCell className="font-medium">{info.resume}</TableCell> */}
                <TableCell className="font-medium">
                  {info.description.length > 50
                    ? `${info.description.substring(0, 50)}...`
                    : info.description}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="font-medium">
                  <EditInfoForm info={info} />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="font-medium">
                  <DeleteInfoButton id={info.id} />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>

        {/* EXPERIENCE TABLE */}
        <div className=" flex items-center shadow-md rounded-lg bg-primary p-4 ">
          <h1 className="font-bold pl-5 text-primary-foreground">
            Experience Form
          </h1>
        </div>
        <ExperienceForm exp={exp} />
        <Table>
          <TableCaption>Experience Form</TableCaption>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHead className="w-[100px]">Job Title</TableHead>
              <TableHead>Company</TableHead>
              <TableHead>Year</TableHead>
              <TableHead className="text-right">Action</TableHead>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {experiences.map((experience) => (
              <TableRow key={experience.id}>
                <TableCell className="font-medium">
                  {experience.jobtitle}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{experience.company}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  {experience.year.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" })}{" "}
                  {experience.year.getFullYear()}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-right">
                  <EditExperienceForm exp={experience} />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-right">
                  <DeleteExperienceButton id={experience.id} />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AdminAbout
```

i tried the solution from vercel [text](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component) but still same error

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass custom props to page components. Page components can accept only,

```
export interface PageProps {
  params?: any
  searchParams?: any
}
```